# Matplotlib plot legend shows markers twice

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

The legend in my plot shows the marker icon twice in the legend

[image: Code output]

The code that produced this plot is given below

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

N = 15

colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, N))

df = []

for i in range(N):
    s = 'NAME %d' % i
    df.append(dict(x=random.random(), y=random.random(), name=s))

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
c = 0
labels = []

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
for name, group in df.groupby('name'):

    x = group['x'].values[0]
    y = group['y'].values[0]

    color = colors[c]
    c += 1

    ax.plot(x, y, color=color, marker='o', linestyle='', label=name)

    labels.append(name)

handels, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handels, labels)
```

Why is this happening?

My actual `df` has multiple entries for each name so that's why I do a `groupby`.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: The default make more sense if you have a non-empty line style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can either [set](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) `plt.legend(loc=...,numpoints =1)` directly or create a [style sheet](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html) and set `legend.numpoints     : 1`

If you use a linux system: place your stylesheets in `~/.config/matplotlib/stylelib/` you can use them with `plt.style.use([your_style_sheet])`. Additionally, you can e.g. make one sheet for the colors etc. and one for the size:  `plt.style.use([my_colors,half_column_latex])`

Comment: Awesome thanks, why on Earthy is `numpoints=1` NOT the default?